# Rationalizing the denominators of $\frac1{\sqrt[12]{16}+\sqrt[12]{8}+\sqrt[12]{4}}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt[4]{8}+\sqrt[4]{4}+\sqrt[4]{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two problems which I think have similar solutions.

> Simplify so that the denominator does not have any root expressions:
>   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[12]{16}+\sqrt[12]{8}+\sqrt[12]{4}} \qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{8}+\sqrt[4]{4}+\sqrt[4]{2}}$$

I have tried to use the identity $a^n-b^n=(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+b^{n-1})$, but can not be applied.

How can I solve them?

Comment: Note:  $(1+x+x^2)(1-x)=1-x^3$

Answer (score 1):

For $\sqrt[12]2=a,a^{12}=2$

$$\dfrac1{a^4+a^3+a^2}=\dfrac1{a^2(1+a+a^2)}=\dfrac{1-a}{a^2(1-a^3)}$$ for $1-a\ne0$

Again $$\dfrac{1-(a^3)^4}{1-a^3}=1+a^3+a^6+a^9$$ for $1-a^3\ne0$

Answer (score 1):

put $x=2^{1/12}$,

$2^{1/3}+2^{1/4}+2^{1/6}=x^4+x^3+x^2$

$1=x^{12}-1=(x^6-1)(x^6+1)=(x^3+1)(x^3-1)(x^6+1)
$ then,

$\dfrac{1}{x^2(x^2+x+1)}=\dfrac{(x-1)(x^3+1)(x^6+1)}{x^2}=\dfrac{x^{10}(x-1)(x^3+1)(x^6+1)}{2}$=former //

latter's is same.